# Storing user input whilst still asking questions

Tags: c

Firstly, i know the source code below is long and you're not really supposed to post code like this, but i really don't understand why it's not working or how i could explain my issue without posting it like this.

Im trying to store the answer to each of the questions asked in it and display them at the end of the script. The biggest problem im having is that i get the error
`"subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector scanf("%s", a[i].incdest);"`

The program doesn't accept a[i].incdest. it does this for all of the array values.

it is also saying that in function main variable "comp1" is undeclared.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int c_s(char*, char*);

typedef struct
{
    char constab[30];
    char vicwit[15];
    char witdet[200];
    char incdest[300];
    char comp1[15];
    char comp2[200];;
} sheetstore;

#define ARRAYLEN 2

sheetstore a[ARRAYLEN];
FILE *fp;

int main()
{
    int i, a;
    char wit[10] = "witness";
    char yes[10] = "yes";
    char comp1[10];

    fp = fopen("sheetstore.dat","a+");

    printf("Hate crime reporting system\n\n\n");

    printf("If the crime you are reporting is an emergency,\nplease call 999, do not proceed any further with this form\n\n\n\nPlease press enter to confirm you have read the above and continue\n");
    char enter = 0;
    while (enter != '\r' && enter != '\n') { enter = getchar(); }

    for( i=0; i<ARRAYLEN ; i++)
    {
        printf("Which police constabulary did the offence take place in?\n\n");
        scanf("%s", a[i].constab);
        printf("Are you a victim or witness of the crime?\nPlease answer victim/witness\n\n");
        scanf("%s", a[i].comp1);
        int res1 = (strcmp (comp1, wit));
        if(res1 == 0){
            printf("Please enter the details including phone number and address of any other witnesses that were present\n");
        }
        scanf("%s", a[i].witdet);
        else{
            printf("Where did the incident take place?\nIf in a house please provide the full address including postcode\n");
            scanf("%s", a[i].incdest);
        }

        fwrite(&a[i], sizeof(a), 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    fopen("sheetstore.dat", "r");
    for(i=0; i<ARRAYLEN; i++)
    {
        fread(&a[i], sizeof(a), 1, fp );
        printf("Which police constabulary did the offence take place in? : %s\n", a[i].constab);
        printf("Are you a victim or witness of the crime? : %s\n", a[i].comp1);
        printf("Please enter the details including phone number and address of any other witnesses that were present : %s\n", a[i].witdet);
        printf("Where did the incident take place? : %s\n", a[i].incdest);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if it's C source code, it's very very likely not a *script*.

Comment: And your `a` is not an array, so what did you expect and **why**?

Comment: in which line do you get the error? And yes what Felix says, why do you treat an int as a string array? Maybe try `sheetstore a;` instead

Comment: I get an error in every line that i use a[i]. how can i declare this so its seen as an array and still stores the information i need?

Comment: Alright, I didn't even see that global. Well, then it's time to learn about scopes and shadowing and why to avoid it. While you're at it, start using **meaningful variable names**, then such things won't happen :o

Comment: @user3121023 Good catch, I totally didn't see the global declaration...

Comment: Does anyone know why when ive made the changes, the if statement has stopped working?

Comment: the posted code does not compile! It causes the compiler to output several 'error' messages and several 'warning' messages.  Please correct and re-post.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the function: `getchar()` returns a `int`, not a `char`  So this statement: `char enter = 0;` should be: `int enter = 0;`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERs modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  Because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input

Comment: in the struct definition, this field: `char comp2[200];;` contains a stray semicolon

Comment: regarding: `char yes[10] = "yes";` the array `yes[]` is not used, so should be eliminated

Comment: regarding: `fwrite(&a[i], sizeof(a), 1, fp);`  this will output the whole array `a[]` when all that is ready to be output is the first instance of the struct: sheetstore.  Suggest: `fwrite(&a[i], sizeof(sheetstore), 1, fp);` and be sure to check the returned value (==1) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this statement: `int i, a;`  masks the prior definition of `a[]` "sheetstore a[ARRAYLEN];".   While correcting this error, strongly suggest using variable names that indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while``switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line. 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 1):

the main issue that i saw in your code, is that you shadowed the array `a` (`sheetstore a[ARRAYLEN];`) by declaring an `int` with the same name in your `main()`.

you also had a `scanf` stament mislocated.

i fixed your code and put in a comment for every change - now, i don't persume to check the functionality of your code but at least this will compile and hopefully will give you a better understanding where you were wrong - from here it is up to you:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int c_s(char*, char*);

typedef struct
{
    char constab[30];
    char vicwit[15];
    char witdet[200];
    char incdest[300];
    char comp1[15];
    char comp2[200];;
} sheetstore;

#define ARRAYLEN 2

sheetstore sheetArr[ARRAYLEN]; //change this 'a' to avoid shadowing by the decleration on 'int a' in main
FILE *fp;

int main()
{
    int i, a;
    char wit[10] = "witness";
    char yes[10] = "yes";
    char comp1[10];

    fp = fopen("sheetstore.dat","a+");

    printf("Hate crime reporting system\n\n\n");

    printf("If the crime you are reporting is an emergency,\nplease call 999, do not proceed any further with this form\n\n\n\nPlease press enter to confirm you have read the above and continue\n");
    char enter = 0;
    while (enter != '\r' && enter != '\n') { enter = getchar(); }

    for( i=0; i<ARRAYLEN ; i++)
    {
        printf("Which police constabulary did the offence take place in?\n\n");
        scanf("%s", sheetArr[i].constab);//change name from 'a'
        printf("Are you a victim or witness of the crime?\nPlease answer victim/witness\n\n");
        scanf("%s", sheetArr[i].comp1);//change name from 'a'
        int res1 = (strcmp (sheetArr[i].comp1, wit));//compare with the value set in the struct
        if(res1 == 0){
            printf("Please enter the details including phone number and address of any other witnesses that were present\n");
            /*this scanf should be inside the brackets of 'if(res1 == 0)' */
            scanf("%s", sheetArr[i].witdet);//change name from 'a'
        }
        else{
            printf("Where did the incident take place?\nIf in a house please provide the full address including postcode\n");
            scanf("%s", sheetArr[i].incdest);//change name from 'a'
        }

        fwrite(&sheetArr[i], sizeof(sheetstore), 1, fp);//write a single struct
    }
    fclose(fp);

    fopen("sheetstore.dat", "r");
    for(i=0; i<ARRAYLEN; i++)
    {
        fread(&sheetArr[i], sizeof(sheetstore), 1, fp );//read a single struct
        printf("Which police constabulary did the offence take place in? : %s\n", sheetArr[i].constab);
        printf("Are you a victim or witness of the crime? : %s\n", sheetArr[i].comp1);
        printf("Please enter the details including phone number and address of any other witnesses that were present : %s\n", sheetArr[i].witdet);
        printf("Where did the incident take place? : %s\n", sheetArr[i].incdest);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. corrects the first 50+ lines of your code.
2. Please correct your posted code so it cleanly compiles
3. for flexibility, separates the definition of the struct from the typedef of the struct
4. properly checks for error indications from system functions
5. honors the right margin (usually 72 or 80 characters)
6. replaces the CPU cycle intensive calls to `printf()` with calls to `puts()` when appropriate
7. This is only a guide for the first 50 lines of the OPs code.  It is not a complete code replacement.

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// prototypes
int c_s(char*, char*);

struct sSheet
{
    char constab[30];
    char vicwit[15];
    char witdet[200];
    char incdest[300];
    char comp1[15];
    char comp2[200];
};
typedef struct sSheet sheetstore;

#define ARRAYLEN 2

sheetstore a[ARRAYLEN];


FILE *fp;

int main( void )
{
    int i;
    char wit[10] = "witness";
    //char yes[10] = "yes";
    char comp1[10];

    fp = fopen("sheetstore.dat","a+");
    if( !fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen for appending to 'sheetstore.dat' failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    puts("Hate crime reporting system\n\n\n");

    puts("If the crime you are reporting is an emergency,\n"
         "please call 999, "
         " do not proceed any further with this form\n\n\n\n"
         "Please press enter"
         " to confirm you have read the above and continue\n");
    int enter = 0;

    while (enter != '\r' && enter != '\n')
    {
        enter = getchar();
    }

    for( i=0; i<ARRAYLEN ; i++)
    {
        puts("Which police constabulary did the offence take place in?\n\n");
        if( scanf("%29s", a[i].constab) != 1)
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for which police constabulary failed" );
            fclose( fp );  // cleanup
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful
```

Comment: your counsels above are very good, but your proposed code will compile properly since you're using **exit** and **EXIT_FAILURE** both of which are in **stdlib.h**, which you didn't *include*. In addition, there is not such `array of struct` **a** available in your stack (body of the main function).

Comment: @eapetcho,  coded edited per your comment,  Note the array of struct is still in the global data, as the OP originally placed it,   Also this answer is just for the first (approx) 50 lines of the code, to point the OP in the right direction,  I.E. it is not a complete code

Answer (score 0):

In addition to some useful comments posted above (meaningful variable names, line width not to be too long for readability), in general sense, your problem is due to two thing: in the body of the **main** function you declare an **int  a** which is used instead of your global array **a[ARRAYLEN]**. Hence, you cannot refence **a[i].incdet** etc. Just comment or remove the **int a** from the **main** function. Secondly, your **scanf("%s", a[i].witdet);** should be in the body of the if statement above according to the program logic. I you do these two changes, the code will compile. However if you pass **-Wall -Werror** to the compiler, it will yields an error like **error: unused variable ‘yes’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
     char yes[10] = "yes";**. Just comment this line to avoid using uncessary memory space on the stack.